# Excel VBA: Refresh All and Save

Tags: excel, vba, save, refresh

I have a very very simply task of wanting to refresh all on the workbook (which only contain 3 tables with external data) and save it every 5 minutes.
I currently have the workbook running an auto save every 5 minutes via:

```
Sub SaveWb()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "SaveWb"
End Sub
```

&

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "SaveWb"
End Sub
```

And the tables refreshes using the connection properties of background auto refresh in 5 minutes.
However, I kept running into the problem where excel would prompt:

"This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue? [OK] [Cancel]"

I wonder if I can have the refresh running in VBA as well so they can run nicely without holding up the refreshes. While this seem like a easy job with the `wb.RefreshAll` function but my non-existant vba skill does not allow me to put them together....

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I experimented a little and the by editing part of the code and it now works:

```
Sub SaveWb()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "SaveWb"
End Sub
```

No more "This will cancel a pending data refresh. Continue?"

Comment: this doesn't work when you call it from another sub

Answer (score 1):

Needs to call Application.DisplayAlerts=False to disable the warnings